# How to make an object to copy another object's transformations which has been animated through modifiers

Tags: animation, modifiers, screw-modifier

So I have a Circle mesh which has a screw modifier + 2 simple deform modifiers (1 to bend on Y axis and one to bend on X axis) Both the Screw Modifier and the Simple deform modifiers are animated in order to create a spring that oscillates across 3 axis.

Now, this spring is moving very nice, but I want to parent another object on top of that spring. How do I do it ?

I cannot parent to a vertex since there is no vertex movement from the original Circle mesh, the whole movement is generated via the modifiers, and the mesh is a simple circle that stays in one place.

I cannot even use constraints because of the same issue.

So I am now forced to animated frame by frame the other object to follow the spring movement, but that takes ages...

Is there any other way I can achieve that ? I'm guessing geometry nodes will be the place to go but how to set up something like this ?

Thanks if anyone have an answer to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an idea with geonodes, to pick the last n vertices of your spring and use the mean position of those to place your second mesh... same with normals to get some kind of rotation value. That's assuming when modifiers generate the mesh the last indices are in the end of spring...

[image: node setup]

[a blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vca8ng88t3y0g7r/spring.blend?dl=1)

Comment: just to clarify, I ended up using one vertex instead of a few of them as the answer reads, it was way more stable... you can use a face to get the transforms too, just change Domain Size and both Attribute Statistic nodes to use Faces and maybe -Index to 1

Comment: Thank you ! Well done I was looking exactly for this

Comment: you're welcome, animating screw modifier adds some more fun...